# Is it possible to read system fan RPM in Java? (Win 7)

Tags: java, windows, arduino, hardware

I would like to read RPMs of the (Windows 7) system fans in Java (like, for example, the application SpeedFan does) to use them for an Arduino based LED project (make fan appear slowly moving by PWMing leds). However, the system has a fan controller so I have to read the rpm continuously. Found nothing after Googling, only a tutorial of how to read the RPM directly from the yellow wire on an Arduino (however, this is not a solution, because I wouldn't like to do hardware modifications on the system itself). Anyone got ideas?

Comment: As this is hardware specific, you would need to find a command line tool which will tell you this.  You can runn such a command line tool from Java.

Comment: If there is a windows API, just call it using JNA

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution is using **JNI** or **JNA**. With it you can use all WinAPI functions, as a result you can get all info what you want. If in the future you'll want read another system info you already have base structure, it's good scalability.

Also you can try find third-party program and get needed info from it, but it's bad idea because maybe in the future when you'll setup another version your third-party program maybe will not work.